# Update mongo db collection to create new field with unique values without impacting existing data using mongo go driver

Tags: go, bson, mongo-go

I am new to mongo and mongo go driver. Need to add new field "uri" to my collection with existing data - using mongo go driver. New field needs to be populated with unique values so that unique index can be created on it. the collection uses _id  as well, if there is a way we can populate new field based on _id field that will work as well.

I am trying below code, not sure how to populate unique values.

//Step1: update all documents to add new field with unique values

```
 _, err := myColl.UpdateMany(
    ctx,
        bson.D{},// select all docs in collection 
        bson.D{
            {"$set", bson.D{{"uri", GenerateRandomUniqueString()}}},
        },
    )
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
```

// then next step is to create index on this field:

```
key := bson.D{{"uri", 1}}
opt := options.Index().SetName("uri-index").SetUnique(true)
model := mongo.IndexModel{Keys: key, Options: opt}

_, err = myColl.Indexes().CreateOne(ctx, model)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
```

Once the index is set up, old records will marked read only, but we can not delete those. New data will have unique 'uri' string value.
Any help is much appreciated.

Using above code fails while unique index creation, as the same value is used for backfill.

I tried this as well:

```
func BackFillUri(db *mongo.Database) error {

myColl := db.Collection("myColl")

ctx := context.Background()

cursor, err := myColl.Find(ctx, bson.M{})
if err != nil {
    return err
}

defer cursor.Close(ctx)
for cursor.Next(ctx) {
    var ds bson.M
    if err = cursor.Decode(&ds); err != nil {
    return err
    }
    
    _, err1 := myColl.UpdateOne(
        ctx,
        bson.D{"_id": ds.ObjectId},
        bson.D{
        {"$set", bson.D{{"uri", rand.Float64()}}},
        },
    )
    if err1 != nil {
        return err1
    }
}
return nil
```

}

But i am getting quite a few errors and not sure if any of the above logic is correct

Comment: So what do you need help with? With the logic to use unique values?

Comment: @icza thanks for your response, The issue is, it only calls the GenerateRandomUniqueString() once and thus attempts to add same string for all documents in myColl., resulting in to index creation failure. Whole purpose of backfilling the data is to allow the unique index creation. I am looking for an option where I can update it with different unique values for each document so that unique index can be created. I tried with other call updateOne, but then i am not sure how to use cursor or pass document to it and iterate over it. I can do it in shell or java, but mongo-go is too new for me.

Answer (score 1):

I finally used below code, hope it helps someone who's new like me :-)

```
const charset = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz" +
  "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789"

func RandomUniqueString(length int) string {
  return StringWithCharset(length, charset)
}

var seededRand *rand.Rand = rand.New(
  rand.NewSource(time.Now().UnixNano()))

func StringWithCharset(length int, charset string) string {
  b := make([]byte, length)
  for i := range b {
    b[i] = charset[seededRand.Intn(len(charset))]
  }
  return string(b)
}

// Adds index on uri
func AddUriIndex(db *mongo.Database) error {

    mycoll := db.Collection("mycoll")
    ctx := context.Background()
    
    
    //backfill code starts
    
    type attribute struct {
        Key   string      `bson:"key"`
        Value interface{} `bson:"value"`
    }
    
    type item struct {
        ID                 primitive.ObjectID `bson:"_id"`
        ResourceAttributes []attribute        `bson:"resourceAttributes,omitempty"`
    }

    cursor, err := mycoll.Find(ctx, primitive.M{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    
    defer cursor.Close(ctx)
    for cursor.Next(ctx) {
        var result item
        if err = cursor.Decode(&result); err != nil {
        return err
        }
        //fmt.Println("Found() result:", result)
        
        filter := primitive.M{"_id": result.ID}
        update := primitive.M{"$set": primitive.M{"uri": RandomUniqueString(32)}}
        if _, err := mycoll.UpdateOne(ctx, filter, update); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    
    //add uri-index starts
    
    key := bson.D{{"uri", 1}}
    opt := options.Index().
            SetName("uri-index").
            SetUnique(true)
    model := mongo.IndexModel{Keys: key, Options: opt}
    
    _, err = mycoll.Indexes().CreateOne(ctx, model)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    return nil
}
```